# Sharepoint : Collect data from user with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, workflow

I would to collect data from user in my visual studio workflow. With sharepoint designer it's very easy with "Collect data from user" you can create a task and add attributs to collect. A email will be send to collect data from user.
I would do the same process in my visual studio workflow.
I haven't found any tools that can do this.
Any ideas ?

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have really found my answer. You have to create an approval workflow.

http://approvalworkflow.codeplex.com/